# qobject_cast returning null

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qobject

I am trying to cast from QObject* to a custom class type, but the pointer that is supposed to receive this cast is always NULL.

The relevant lines of code:

This is the function with the cast

```
void CFCInterface::fnAddConn()
{

CFCConnections* f_pConn ;
f_pConn= new CFCConnections(this);


QObject* f_pObject = this;

while(f_pObject)
{
    f_pConn = qobject_cast<CFCConnections*>(f_pObject);
    if(f_pConn)
    break;  

    f_pObject = f_pObject->parent();

}
if( f_pConn == 0 ) 
return;
```

}

This is called in the main constructor of FCInterface:

```
`CFCInterface::CFCInterface(QObject* parent): CInterface(parent), CFCAbstract() 
{
    //Some other functions being called
    fnAddConn();

}

CFCInterface::~CFCInterface()
{

}
`
```

f_pConn remains NULL. If anyone could take a guess at why this is so, I'll have some lead to follow.

For reference I'll add the class and header file. They don't have any functionality other than to make this cast work.

Header:

```
#include headers

class CFCConnections: public CResourceItem
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CFCConnections(QObject*);
    ~CFCConnections();



};


#endif
```

Class:

```
#include headers

CFCConnections::CFCConnections(QObject* parent) : CResourceItem(parent)
{

    //Empty contructor


}
CFCConnections::~CFCConnections()
{

}
```

PS: I don't think what the code is trying to do is relevant here, but in case anyone is wondering FCInterface is the parent class to FCConnections. I am trying to implement a tree model list where every item has its own class and functionality. I am using the cast to make "Connections" appear under FCInterface.

Comment: Add a breakpoint at "QObject* f_pObject = this;", then inspect what this is actually pointing to and follow through with the debugger until you get to the cast.

Comment: @ManuelH I did just this. `f_pConn` gets initialised as a null pointer. In the line you asked about, `f_pObject` gets the address of _this_. After that the `qobject_cast` fails and `f_pConn` remains as a null pointer. `f_pObject` gets the address of the parent and the loop gets restarted. The address assigned to `f_pObject` in the end changes with every loop and the loop exits when `f_pObject` becomes a null pointer. I don't get any of this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple: the object you perform this action on is not a descendant of a `CFConnections`.

You need to be able to use your finger to point to `QObject` constructor invocations and/or `setParent` calls that are performed to establish such parent-child relationship.

Your code example is not complete and you have lots of irrelevant details. Provide a *single file* example that shows the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 1.  I admit the class file was unnecessary, but I don't know how I could explain the problem in one file. This code is complete in my opinion, that is why I am confused by this problem. 2. The Q_OBJECT macro in the header file should take care setting up the parent-child relationship right?

Comment: Remember how C++ works. Any code in multiple files can be condensed into one file. The `Q_OBJECT` macro doesn't establish any sort of parent-child relationship. I've told you what you need to establish it: take your finger, literally, and point to constructors that you pass the parent pointer to, or `setParent` invocations that you similarly pass the parent pointer to. If you can't do it, it won't work. It's really that simple. Nothing to it. Use your finger to point at code. If code doesn't exist, write it.

Answer (score 0):

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

Turns out the mistake was in the first line. I wrote `CFCConnections* f_pConn = 0` thinking this would do the appropriate memory allocation for me. 
Changing that to the following fixed the problem:

```
CFCConnections* f_pConn;
f_pConn = new CFCConnections(this);
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  All you've done here is leak memory if your cast succeeds. Perhaps, like your example above, there's just not enough code to give anyone the context of what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @RetiredNinja what if I delete the pointer in the end? And I really don't understand what my code is missing? It is a question regarding the application of `qobject_cast`, could you please tell me what context would help here?

Comment: You've shown about a dozen lines of code, presumably from a function, but we don't know what the function is named, what parameters it takes, or how it is called. If you're happy with your solution I guess you can just move on, but my gut says it's not correct, and based on what you've shared, nobody can tell you what correct is. There's a reason we ask for a complete example and not just snippets.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Terribly sorry. I wasn't trying to be difficult. I have added pretty much everything I can to clear things up. I really need to understand why my solution might be a bad one and how I would fix it.